# run_id on parameter server does not match declared run_id

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set up several `roslaunch` files to be launched at system startup using `systemd`. However at the startup they show the above error and fail. When I set the `systemd` services to be restarted on failure, launch files are relaunched when failed and work fine. What might I be doing wrong here? **Declared `run_id` for each `roslaunch` seems to be different from each other at the first launch.**

The error is in the following format

```
run_id on parameter server does not match declared run_id: 686cb5dc-01cf-11e9-ab7c-b10995016401 vs 68b27f9a-01cf-11e9-ab7c-b10995016401
```

Here's a sample script that runs a launch file

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /my/workspace/path/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch /launch/file/path/myfile.launch
```

Here's the format of the systemd services I use

```
[Unit]
Description=Unit description
Wants=roscore.service
BindsTo=roscore.service

[Service]
User=username
ExecStart=/script/that/runs/the/launch/file.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`roscore.service` starts a roscore. I am using `kinetic` on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310848/run_id-on-parameter-server-does-not-match-declared-run_id/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

With this you only reduce the likelihood of things going wrong. A better solution in my opinion would be to add --wait to the roslaunch commands as documented here:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#Launch_syntax

This way roslaunch will wait until it detects a roscore (as configured per ROS_MASTER_URI) and you avoid the less clean "sleep solution".

---

Originally posted by [t-low](https://answers.ros.org/users/45280/t-low/) with karma: 56 on 2019-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-06-17**:
This should be the accepted answer.

**Comment by [rjosodtssp](https://answers.ros.org/users/38070/rjosodtssp/) on 2020-07-14**:
very useful